# NNTP get MessageId after article POST

Tags: c#, nntp

I just started using http://nntpclientlib.codeplex.com/ and just posted my first article. But I don't know how to get the message-Id to the article that I posted. 
I have set up the article with only a subject, newsgroup and from-headers. 
I got a 240 response from the server after posting the article - but I don't see any way to get the Message-Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out myself: You just have to add a random message-Id to your article-headers. If it is not already used by another article, the POST will be successfull.

Comment: While the message-id is potentially under your control, I would never say it should be "random" -- note that a successful post requires that the server not already have that message-id, but ideally you don't want the id to ever have been used elsewhere (globally unique).